# How to display an uploaded image (both from drag and drop and file upload from computer)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to display an uploaded image using jquery fileupload. I want to support both drap and drop and normal file uploading from computer. However, i can only display files that are dropped. I want the uploaded image to be shown in the `div` `#uploadedImg` after it gets uploaded. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my jsfiddle (the code does not fit in a code snippet because I could not find the cdn for jquery upload): http://jsfiddle.net/ja5q7u0x/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I had to do,
1. In your fileupload function defination you have not mentioned the input id. **Line#1216**

`fileInput: '#up1',`

2. In your add function look at **line#1221** - i made it change to expect value from input field

`var dataTransfer =  e.originalEvent.dataTransfer|| e.originalEvent.target;`

Just for my convinience i defied an id for input type=file **Line#1261**

Here is fixed code.
http://jsfiddle.net/ja5q7u0x/22/